# Is it possible to replicate the functionality of Jupyter Notebooks cells when debugging a Python script?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've been learning Python by using Jupyter Notebooks and have now moved over into writing normal Python scripts using VS Code (attempting OOP). As a simple example let's say I have a script that starts with a very slow function and then ends with a quick function. To debug the second function in a Notebook I would split these two functions into two cells. That way, I could run the first, slow one and store the variables. I could then run the second, fast function, make a change, rerun etc. In VS Code with the code in a normal script I have to run the whole thing end to end which takes a long time.

Is there any way to replicate this kind of debugging process in VS Code with normal Python scripts? Or indeed am I just going about debugging in completely the wrong way and I need to learn it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that when the first part is run once, the generated variables can continue to be used, and can be repeatedly modified to run in the second part?

Have you ever used jupyter notebooks in vscode?
I tried it and found that it can run separately.Reference:[this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook).

If you've used Jupiter notebooks in vscode, you could try checking the debugging process again.  Reference:[this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_debug-a-jupyter-notebook).

Besides, if it still doesn't work, hopefully you could provide more relevant information,for example: how do you operate debugging?

Comment: Maybe you can look into this page:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-february-2020-release/.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer. I have used JNs in VS Code but there's limited functionality vs using the editor for .py files. I've actually found the AREPL extension which works pretty well for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you for providing us with your solution!